# php form - 2 buttons (one to destroy session and reload page and one to proceed to next page)

Tags: php, javascript, html, session

On the page 'selecteditems.php' I have a form like this:

```
<form method="POST" name="selecteditems" action="nextpage.php">
....i have some code here to display the values of the SESSION array in a table....
<input type="button" name="clear" value="Clear Session" onclick="window.location='selecteditems.php'">
<input type="submit" name="next" value="Go to Checkout">
</form>
```

Before the form on the 'selecteditems.php' page I have some code to add data ($_REQUEST params from the page that called 'selecteditems.php') to a $_SESSION array (this is working fine).
Inside the form I have some code to display everything inside the $_SESSION array (this is working fine). If the session is empty it should print "session is empty".

My problem:
I want to be able to click on the "Clear Session" button and have the session destroyed as well as the 'selecteditems.php' page reloading to say "session is empty" . If, the "Go to Checkout" button is clicked i would like to simply be sent to the nextpage.php page.

Any help would be appreciated in getting the 'selecteditems.php' to reload and echo "session is empty" after i have deleted the session.

Comment: have you tried anything? there is no `problem` if you have not tried anything

Comment: That's nice, @toop. A question would also be nice.

Comment: i have tried: if (isset($_REQUEST['clear']))
{
 session_destroy();
}   but that doesn't reload the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put your clear session button as submit button with `type="submit"` (you have it as `type="button"`, which <s>has inconsistent behaviour across browsers</s> does nothing) and then you can just treat it as a normal submission process:

```
if(isset($_POST['clear'])) {
    session_destroy(); // Or other session-unsetting logic
    header("Location: selecteditems.php"); // Reload your page
}

if(isset($_POST['next'])) {
    //next page logic
}
```

You might not even need to reload the clear session page. For the 'session cleared message' you could either add the logic to the `$_POST['clear']` block, or redirect to 'selecteditems.php?msg=cleared' and search for a `$_GET['msg']` and output the correct message, up to you :)

Comment: +1 But just one clarification: `input type="button"` works quite consistently in browsers: it does nothing by default.